# How can I solve this specific python circular import?

Tags: python, marshmallow

Can someone help me with this python circular import?

The file `measurement_schema.py` imports `elementary_process_schema`. And the file `elementary_process_schema.py` imports `measurement_schema`.

I need to use the referenced class in the last line of each declared class. e.g.: The last line of **measurement_schema.py:** `elementary_processes = fields.Nested(ElementaryProcessSchema, many=True)`

***Full code:***

**measurement_schema.py**

```
from marshmallow import fields

from api import ma
from api.model.schema.elementary_process_schema import ElementaryProcessSchema


class MeasurementSchema(ma.Schema):


    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()
    description = fields.Str()
    created_on = fields.Str()

    elementary_processes = fields.Nested(ElementaryProcessSchema, many=True)
```

**elementary_process_schema.py**

```
from marshmallow import fields

from api import ma
from api.model.schema.ar_rl_schema import ARRLSchema
from api.model.schema.data_item_schema import DataItemSchema
from api.model.schema.elementary_process_type_schema import ElementaryProcessTypeSchema
from api.model.schema.measurement_schema import MeasurementSchema


class ElementaryProcessSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.Str()
    operation = fields.Str()
    reference = fields.Str()
    created_on = fields.Str()

    elementary_process_type = fields.Nested(ElementaryProcessTypeSchema)
    data_itens = fields.Nested(DataItemSchema, many=True)
    AR_RLs = fields.Nested(ARRLSchema, many=True)

    measurement = fields.Nested(MeasurementSchema)
```

I know there are many topics about that issue. However, I cannot solve my specific circular reference issue.

Comment: Did you explore implementing a factory pattern here, here is an example https://mehulkar.com/blog/2017/04/the-factory-pattern-and-circular-dependencies/ - In your class you probably need to inject ElementaryProcessSchema in MeasurementSchema and vice-versa in a factory.

Comment: Thank you Hussain. I used the smassey's tip. It is simple and works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with ORMs and with python it's often solved the same way: you identify the relationship by name (string) instead of reference (class/instance). It's well documented in marshmallows doc here:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html#two-way-nesting

in short, try something like this (I have 0 experience with marshmallow, so this is in no way tested):

```
elementary_processes = fields.Nested(ElementaryProcessSchema, many=True)
# would become:
elementary_processes = fields.Nested("ElementaryProcessSchema", many=True)
```

and

```
measurement = fields.Nested(MeasurementSchema)
# becomes:
measurement = fields.Nested("MeasurementSchema")
```

Comment: Additionally, I should to include "exclude=('boundaries', )" as reported next: 

measurement = fields.Nested("MeasurementSchema", exclude=('elementary_processes', ))